# Bootstrap 3 Grid: Move elements between rows

Tags: responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

While learning Twitter Bootstrap 3 to create responsive web pages I faced a problem:
*How to move element up from one row to another?*
 I need something like col-md-push / col-md-pull but for vertical direction.

For example, on desktop screen element **D** is in second row, but on tablet it should be in first one:

*Desktop:*
| A | B | C |
| D | E | F |

*Tablet:*
| A | D |
| B | C |
| E | F |

*Phone:*
| A |
| D |
| B |
| E |
| C |
| F |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution using nested columns. A and D elements are grouped in one column. On desktop screen (col-md) they occupy 12 columns each, so that D is placed below A. On tablet screen (col-sm) A and D are equal size (6) so that they fit in one row.

Complete code: http://jsfiddle.net/UNs25/1/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">       

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="A">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="D">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="B">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E">            
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="C">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="F">            
        </div>      

    </div>      
</div>
```