# Bootstrap moving elements between unnested rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do something very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22522585/bootstrap-3-grid-move-elements-between-rows) except I need to move an element through multiple rows, not just one.

In desktop mode it should look like this (which my code currently does):

| A | B |

| C | D | E |

In tablet mode I need it to look like this:

| B |

| D |

| C | E |

| A |

The trouble is the A moving from the top to the bottom.  Here is the html I have so far that does everything except move the A:

```
<div class="row" id="subheader">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="subnav">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        B       
    </div>      
</div>
<div class="row" id="content">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3">
        D
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-6 col-xs-6" id="services">
        C
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6" id="pagenav">
        E
    </div>
</div>
```

I am hoping this does not require hiding and showing multiple sets of the same content or using jquery, just not sure if bootstrap can move an element like this using push and pull.

Thanks!

Comment: You have them in different rows. So, I don't think you're going to be able to do that with the parameters you have specified (no jquery, hide/show on resizes)

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure if there was a way I could nest the rows and still make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer and it works I have tested it now stop dinging me with negative votes. Told you Give me today to do it.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
           <head>
                <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
                <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
                <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="flex-container">
                <header>Header A</header>
                <header>Header B</header>
                    <div class="child">
                        <article class="flex-item">
                            <p>Content C</p>  
                        </article>
                        <article class="flex-item">
                            <p>Content D</p>  
                        </article>
                        <article class="flex-item">
                            <p>Content E</p>  
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <!-- Javascript goes here -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
/* Global Styles */
@charset "utf-8";
*, *:before, *:after{
     -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
             box-sizing: border-box !important;
}

body{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
font-family: "Source Sans Pro","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

html{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6{
    margin: 0 0 35px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

@-moz-document url-prefix(){
    .flex-container{
        width: 100%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}

}

.flex-container{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;   
    flex-flow:row wrap;
}

header{
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
    order:1;
}

/* Flex-box section */
header > *{

}

header:nth-child(1){
    width:100%;
    display: block;
    flex:1 auto;
    order:6;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: deepskyblue;
}

header:nth-child(2){
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: tomato;
    display: block;
    flex:1 auto;
    order:1;
}

.child{
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
    order:2;
    text-align:center;
    flex-flow:row wrap;
}

.child > * {
    padding: 10px;
    display:inline-flex;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1){
    display:block;
    flex:1 auto;
    text-align:center;
    background: gold;
    order:2;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2){
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background: hotpink;
    order:1;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3){
    display:block;
    flex:1 auto;
    text-align:center;
    background: orange;
    order:3;
}

@media(min-width: 800px){
header{
    display:block;
}

    header:nth-child(1){
    width:50%;
    display: block;
    order:1;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: deepskyblue;
}

header:nth-child(2){
    width:50%;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background: tomato;
    display: block;
    order:2;
}

.child > *{
    display:block;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1){
    display:block;
    width:33.333%;
    text-align:center;
    background: gold;
    order:1;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2){
    display:block;
    width:33.333%;
    text-align:center;
    background: hotpink;
    order:2;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(3){
    display:block;
    width:33.333%;
    text-align:center;
    background: orange;
    order:3;
    }
}
```

View the Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/blayderunner123/h09geqz2/

Download it at: [Download](http://https:soldierupdesigns.com/templates/flex.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  This certainly works!  I'm not familiar with all of the css syntax you used so I'll have to look into it...I'm assuming its cross-browser compatible...also, not sure if you meant "you" as in the internet, but I didn't down vote you.

Comment: Ok cool. It is cross browser compatable. And all you need to do is drop it in and change the header to subnet or what ever. Just make sure you change it in the cores pond CSS as well. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Also if you need any more help implementing it just email me at mailto:info@sodierupdesigns.com I would be more than happy to help